# Advanced Custom Fields Flexible Content with Multiple Bootstrap Collapse (Accordion)

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, accordion, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF Flexible Content to allow multiple accordions on the same page. The problem for me is the counting integer. With each new accordion, it starts counting the sections ('#collapse-#') over again. I'm not too PHP savvy.

My code is returning this:

**Accordion 1**

- Collapse 1
- Collapse 2
- Collapse 3

**Accordion 2**

- Collapse 1
- Collapse 2
- Collapse 3

But, I need it to print this:

**Accordion 1**

- Collapse 1
- Collapse 2
- Collapse 3

**Accordion 2**

- Collapse 4
- Collapse 5
- Collapse 6

My code so far:

```
<?php if( have_rows('content') ): ?>
<?php $j=1; while ( have_rows('content') ) : the_row(); ?>
<?php if( get_row_layout() == 'accordion' ): ?>
<?php if( have_rows('sections') ): ?>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion-<?php echo $j; ?>" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
<?php $i=1; while ( have_rows('sections') ) : the_row(); ?>

<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-<?php echo $i; ?>">
<h2 class="panel-title">
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-<?php echo $j; ?>" href="#collapse-<?php echo $i; ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
<?php the_sub_field('question'); ?>
</a>
</h2>
</div>

<div id="collapse-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse <?php if ($i==1) { echo 'in'; } ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-<?php echo $i; ?>">
 <div class="panel-body">
 <?php the_sub_field('answer'); ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php $j++; endwhile; ?>
<?php else : endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution based on Kalen Johnson's [repo](https://github.com/kalenjohnson/wp-bootstrap-acf).

```
<?php if( have_rows('content') ): ?>

<?php $j=1; while ( have_rows('content') ) : the_row(); ?>

<?php if( get_row_layout() == 'accordion' ): ?>

<?php if( have_rows('sections') ): ?>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion-<?php echo $j; ?>" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

<?php $i=1; while ( have_rows('sections') ) : the_row(); ?>

<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading-<?php echo $i; ?>">
<h2 class="panel-title">
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion-<?php echo $j; ?>" href="#collapse-<?php echo $j; ?>-<?php echo $i; ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
<?php the_sub_field('question'); ?>
</a>
</h2>
</div>

<div id="collapse-<?php echo $j; ?>-<?php echo $i; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse <?php if ($i==1) { echo 'in'; } ?>" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-<?php echo $i; ?>">
<div class="panel-body">
<?php the_sub_field('answer'); ?>
</div>
</div>

</div>
<?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php $j++; endwhile; ?>

<?php else : endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed this with "uniqid".

https://codepen.io/herrfischer/pen/yqrZzm

In this case my accordion is a repeater inside a flexible field.

This way every accordion has a uniqe ID:

```
<?php
   // get flexible field
   if ( get_row_layout() == 'columns_row_row_accordion'): ?>

   <?php 
   // create uniqe ID
   $Acc_ID = uniqid(); ?>

   <?php 
   // get repeater
   if( have_rows('accordion_zeile') ) : ?>

   <div id="accordion_<?php echo $Acc_ID; ?>">
   <?php while ( have_rows('accordion_zeile') ) : the_row(); ?>

   ...
```

Example with Bootstrap 4:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <section class="col-12 __ column column_h2">
    <div class="col_inner txt">
      <h2>First Accordion</h2>
    </div>
  </section>


  <section class="column column_accordion __ col-12">
    <div id="accordion_5d7a6419bb876">

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="heading_1_5d7a6419bb876">
          <h4 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_1_5d7a6419bb876" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse_1_5d7a6419bb876">
       111      </button>
          </h4>
        </div>

        <div id="collapse_1_5d7a6419bb876" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading_1_5d7a6419bb876" data-parent="#accordion_5d7a6419bb876" style="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>Praesent porttitor, nulla vitae posuere iaculis, arcu nisl dignissim dolor, a pretium mi sem ut ipsum. Aenean tellus metus, bibendum sed, posuere ac, mattis non, nunc. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent egestas neque eu enim. Fusce convallis metus
              id felis luctus adipiscing.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="heading_2_5d7a6419bb876">
          <h4 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_2_5d7a6419bb876" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse_2_5d7a6419bb876">
       222      </button>
          </h4>
        </div>

        <div id="collapse_2_5d7a6419bb876" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading_2_5d7a6419bb876" data-parent="#accordion_5d7a6419bb876">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>Pellentesque dapibus hendrerit tortor. Phasellus nec sem in justo pellentesque facilisis. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Sed augue ipsum, egestas nec, vestibulum et, malesuada adipiscing, dui. Praesent metus tellus, elementum
              eu, semper a, adipiscing nec, purus.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="heading_3_5d7a6419bb876">
          <h4 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_3_5d7a6419bb876" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse_3_5d7a6419bb876">
       333      </button>
          </h4>
        </div>

        <div id="collapse_3_5d7a6419bb876" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading_3_5d7a6419bb876" data-parent="#accordion_5d7a6419bb876">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Quisque rutrum. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Phasellus dolor. Nunc egestas, augue at pellentesque laoreet, felis eros vehicula leo, at malesuada velit leo quis pede.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>






  <section class="col-12 __ column column_h2">
    <div class="col_inner txt">
      <h2>Another Accordion</h2>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="column column_accordion __ col-12">
    <div id="accordion_5d7a6419bbd35">

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="heading_1_5d7a6419bbd35">
          <h4 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_1_5d7a6419bbd35" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse_1_5d7a6419bbd35">
       111      </button>
          </h4>
        </div>

        <div id="collapse_1_5d7a6419bbd35" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading_1_5d7a6419bbd35" data-parent="#accordion_5d7a6419bbd35" style="">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>Pellentesque libero tortor, tincidunt et, tincidunt eget, semper nec, quam. Suspendisse enim turpis, dictum sed, iaculis a, condimentum nec, nisi. Praesent nonummy mi in odio. In turpis. Duis leo.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header" id="heading_2_5d7a6419bbd35">
          <h4 class="mb-0">
            <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse_2_5d7a6419bbd35" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse_2_5d7a6419bbd35">
       222      </button>
          </h4>
        </div>

        <div id="collapse_2_5d7a6419bbd35" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading_2_5d7a6419bbd35" data-parent="#accordion_5d7a6419bbd35">
          <div class="card-body">
            <p>Nullam accumsan lorem in dui. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Fusce neque. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>






</div>
```